# Python: string to integer as a key

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert a string column in a dataframe to int. The strings should be replaced with an integer as a key value.

Data:

```
user_id site_id 
100     url1.com 
100     url2.com 
100     url1.com 
101     url2.com 
101     url2.com 
101     url2.com
```

Wanted output:

```
user_id site_id 
100     1 
100     2 
100     1 
101     2 
101     2 
101     2
```

I tried to get all unique urls with:

```
names = pd.unique(df.site_id.ravel()) 
urls = pd.Series(np.arange(len(names)), names)
```

and then

```
df["site_id"] = df.applymapp(urls.get)
```

Comment: What did you try so far?...S.O. =/= FREELANCER :D

Comment: Please, Post your try code on by editing your question, to assist you more correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You want [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) to encode the values to ints:

```
In [52]:
df['site_id'] = pd.factorize(df['site_id'])[0] + 1
df

Out[52]:
   user_id  site_id
0      100        1
1      100        2
2      100        1
3      101        2
4      101        2
5      101        2
```

here `factorize` returns an array:

```
In [53]:
pd.factorize(df['site_id'])

Out[53]:
(array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64), Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64'))
```

we want the encoded values in the tuple and add `1` to each:

```
pd.factorize(df['site_id'])[0] + 1
```

Comment: Thanks for that quick solution!!

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Do you know if there is an equivalent for `dask`? Could not ifnd it [in the docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html)